# Opening a .exe file from configurable path

Tags: c#

I would like to know how do I open up a program in C#, in any computer, I only get it to start with

```
Process.Start("C:\Users\\*name*\Desktop\MxMV2\MxMV2 EA\EA\bin\Debug\EA.exe");
```

But I would like to share the program with my friends, and they don't have the same file directory as me. So how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome. There are different approaches for this. You could require the files to be in a common directory, like ```%appdata%```. Otherwise, you could provide the possibility to set the directory via a parameter.

Comment: What is this EA? It may have self registered in the registry. Otherwise you may want to ask user to configure your software by specifying path to that software. This can be automated by checking most common installation pathes or searching the file system.

Comment: Are you sure what it's always installed/copied in the folder in the desktop? Current answers seems assume this.

Answer (score 1):

You are free not to hardcode the desktop path.

```
string desktoppath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
String path = @"MxMV2\MxMV2 EA\EA\bin\Debug\EA.exe";
Process.Start(desktoppath + @"\" + path);
```

Is this something you want?

Comment: And its not working either, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: @bruhmoment, could u kindly show me the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder) enum for this purpose:

```
Process.Start($@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\MxMV2\MxMV2 EA\EA\bin\Debug\EA.exe");
```

Comment: its not doing anything

Comment: @Sinatr, yes, I know. That part was just related to the example that bruhmoment provided in the question. There he used just a regular string and forgot to do proper escaping. But in any case, I'll update the answer

Comment: only  ; expected   but its easy to do that

Comment: Any other anwsers? they all dont work, but i can live without a answer.

Comment: @bruhmoment, can you carefully explain what doesn't work? Do you get an error? Which one?

Comment: @Sinatr I dont get any errors, when I press the button it just doesent do anything, doesent open up the program, or is it just my fault, I dont know alot about C# so it could be that.Oh and EA is a script executor and how do i " check most common installation pathes or searching the file system".

Comment: @bruhmoment let's continue the discussion in a chatroom here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215147/exe-file-open-issue

Comment: @JustShadow I only have 1 rep so i cant talk.